# The meaning of 日本はどうですか

Tags: translation, meaning

I understand that 日本はどうですか can mean a suggestion, like somebody is wondering "where should I go on vacation?" and somebody else answers "日本はどうですか？" - "maybe Japan, how about Japan?" but I tried making a sentence meaning "how do you like Japan?" or "how is Japan?" and I feel like 日本はどうですか also works.

Am I right? Could I ask 日本はどうですか to ask somebody visiting Japan what their impression of Japan is?

Comment: You are basically right. If you want to mean "how do you like Japan?" then you probably want to ask "What do you think about Japan?".「(あなたは)日本についてどう思いますか。」.

Comment: Please write answers in the answer section.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> **日本はどうですか。＝日本を選んだらどうですか。（日本を選ぶといいのではないでしょうか。）＝日本にすればどうですか。（日本にすると良いのではないでしょうか。）**

How about Japan? How about choosing Japan? How about visiting Japan?

> **日本はどうですか。＝日本をどう思いますか。＝日本に住んでみてどう思いますか。＝日本に行ってみてどう思いますか。**

What do you think about Japan? What is your comment/thought/impression about Japan?

You're right! There are two interpretations about 日本はどうですか。